build failed due to gradle
when i try to run the app
.gradle\caches\7.6.3\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             29.6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
i try to create new project but it give the same error

We need some context on the app and where you are running gradle. Is this in Android Studio or in a terminal?
